# Get translation of prismatic joints through C++ API

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I am making a ROS plugin for a cylindrical manipulator. I need to get the translation of the prismatic joint in order to report the position of the end effector. I looked through the Joint API (http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Joint.html) and failed to see a function that would give me this information. I found GetAngle, but that is meaningless for a prismatic joint. The SliderJoint API didn't provide any help either. How do I get the translation of a prismatic joint through the C++ API?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8340/get-translation-of-prismatic-joints-through-c++-api/) by [Robocop87](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1162/robocop87/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-03-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The function is probably badly named, but I believe `GetAngle` for a prismatic joint returns the joint's displacement in meters. See [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/1086/better-documentation-needed-for-joint).

I did a quick test with the GUI. Insert the `Simple Arm` model and on the World tree, select the `arm_wrist_lift_joint`, which is prismatic. Expand `axis1` and you'll see that the joint's lower and upper limits are -0.8 m and 0.1 m respectively. Now expand the joint control panel on the right and apply some forces to move this joint up and down, and you'll see the value of `angle_0` go from one joint limit to the other.

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robocop87](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1162/robocop87/) on 2015-03-29**:
Great, thank you for your answer! I agree, badly named function.

**Comment by [Robocop87](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1162/robocop87/) on 2015-03-30**:
One other question, the GetAngle function returns a math::Angle type which can be resolved to a number using math::Angle::Degree or math::Angle::Radian. If it is a prismatic joint, which do I use? I'll assume radian but I'm not sure.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2015-03-30**:
Radian seems to be the one.